# Fedex Shipping Rates

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, fedex

An order was placed at my store with item that was having 36 Lbs weight and total 25 items were fetched in the same order. But the shipping rate charged by Fedex seems abnormal(order price was $6299 and fedex 3 day freight charges were $3075). Total $9300 were charged to the customer. 
I went to [Fedex ratefinder site](https://www.fedex.com/ratefinder/standalone?method=goToFreight&from=Package) and input the source , destination detials it gave me the following results [image]

I also had enabled logs for fedex and [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QKgGvhu9hKLBBTRYu6fNGPSZk1_4dJAP/view?usp=sharing) is the response that was logged for that particular order. 
Is there something wrong here in the logs? Or is there something wrong at my store end which is causing these rates that are almost 50 percent of the price of order placed?

Comment: Please make your log file Publix for anyone with the link so that we can actually see it

Comment: My bad, I have made it public. please let me know if its still not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The understanding of fedex logs really helped me in solving this issue. The difference in prices calculated was due to different packages and different fedex accounts which led to the deviance in the price calculate.